# Vue Router Guards are not Blocking Guarded Routes When Typed in Address Bar

Tags: authentication, vue.js, navigation, router

I have a simple vue app that I am trying to protect some routes, Ie.: if user is logged in show the dashboard page and block the member-login page. If the user is NOT logged in show the member-login page but block the dashboard page.

It is working on the navigation... so if I am not logged in and click "dashboard" I get redirected to the member-login page. And if I am logged in and click "login" I get redirected to the dashboard page. Cool.

Except if I type the path in the address bar, meaning, if I am logged in and click "login" I get redirected to the dashboard, but if I type /member-login in the address bar it still takes me to the member-login page, and it shouldn't. Same in reverse with the dashboard page if I am not logged in.

I am using the `beforeEach()` method to perform the guards, and here is what I have:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
   let ls = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loggedInMember'));
   if(ls === null && to.name === 'dashboard'){ 
      next('/member-login');
   } else if ( ls !== null && to.name === 'login') { 
      next('/dashboard');
   } else {
      next();
   }
});
```

I should mention that this is a global guard, and it lives in the main.js file of my project.

What am I missing?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue was a stupid mistake on my part...

I had the `router.beforeEach` method below the `new Vue({})` method and it didn't like that. So moving the `beforeEach` method above the `new Vue` method fixed this issue.

**Buggy:**

```
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   router,
   store,
   components: { App },
   template: '<App/>'
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
   let ls = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loggedInMember'));

   if(ls === null && to.name === 'dashboard'){
      next('/member-login');
   } else if ( ls !== null && to.name === 'login') {
      next('/dashboard');
   } else {
      next();
   }
});
```

**Fixed:**

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
   let ls = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loggedInMember'));

   if(ls === null && to.name === 'dashboard'){
      next('/member-login');
   } else if ( ls !== null && to.name === 'login') {
      next('/dashboard');
   } else {
      next();
   }
});

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   router,
   store,
   components: { App },
   template: '<App/>'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean you input the `/member-login` and it takes you to the login page ? It seems to me that it's the right action , or there's some misunderstanding I get?
Can you provide more details ?

Comment: That's correct if the user is NOT logged in. But if the user is logged in it should redirect him to the dashboard page.

Comment: I see, did you change or rewrite the localStorage somewhere ? You can put an breakpoint here to see what happened exactly .

Comment: I'm simply checking to see if the local storage item is present, and if it is then the user is logged in. And I can see in the devtools that the local storage is either there or not. And as I mention, with the navigation buttons it works perfectly, but when typing in the url path, it no longer guards the routes.

Comment: See the resolution in my own answer...stupid oversight on my part.